# Why isn't it possible to use VALUE for inputs in a bootstrap modal? (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, placeholder

I use a bootstrap modal for a form in my code.
So, I need standard-values for two textfields, and I tried to simply use VALUE like

```
    <input type="text" value="myStandardText" ng-model="something">
```

I think it's because of the ng-model, but why? 
And do you know a way to get the same result as with value, too?
(For now, I use "placeholder" instead, but value would be better)

UPDATE: Ok, i got a step closer.

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="e_uname" ng-init="e_uname = 'a std txt'">
```

does the trick, but i need now to set a saved value as init-value.
i added "uname" to my scope, but with input it doesn't work.

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="e_uname" ng-init="e_uname = {{uname}}">
```

I tried also with different quote marks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I found the answer. 
Final solution is:

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="e_uname"  ng-value="uname">
```

Comment: Ok, I found out that its shit. ng-value is just optical. So anyone knows how I can do it with ng-init?